# How do I sort this list by frequency, this is what I've tried and its not what I expected

Tags: python

```
items = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4]
result = sorted(items, key = items.count, reverse= True)
```

This outputs [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 6]

instead of what I expected: [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]

Comment: What's wrong with the output you got? It **is** sorted by frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have succeeded in sorting the list by frequency. The problem is that both 2 and 6 have the same frequency, so their sort order is left unchanged. If you'd like to sort first by frequency, then by value, you can do that easily by exploiting the fact that a tuple is sorted first by the value in index 0, then the value in index 1, and so on.

To do that, we can create a function that constructs a tuple of the item count and the value, and use that function as the sorting key:

```
items = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4]
sort_key = lambda x: (items.count(x), x)
result = sorted(items, key = sort_key, reverse = True)
```

Output:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]
```

Comment: "the order that they get sorted in is arbitrary" - that's not quite right. Python sorting is stable, so elements with equal key values will retain their original order relative to each other.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit the answer. I didn't know that - thought it was implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import collections
lst = [4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4]
from collections import Counter
print([n for n,count in Counter(lst).most_common() for i in range(count)])

>>> [4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]
```

Surprisingly, most methods used to calculate frequency end up with the same problem, but not this one.